# Problems with dynamically resetting object references in vuejs + vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am coding a web app with vuex and firestore. In my main.js, under created(), I am calling a vuex action (defined in a store module) to query the firestore db and bind a certain subset of the objects in the collection to vuex, restricted programmatically. Summing up:

Let me simplify my question. Here is my structure:

```
<template> has a v-for list feeded by the computed() property below.

mounted () a function calling vuexfire action binding db RESTRICTED collection to state.ref

computed () some c. property returning a list of state.ref

methods () some method callong vuexfire action binding db UN***RESTRICTED collection relative to some WHERE TO parameter to state.ref
```

I want to be able to call the method sometimes to reset state.ref to the UNRESTRICTED set of db objects.

My problem is that calling the method triggers no error, but seems to fail: the computed() list returns no object.

Comment: Can you update the question to show your action methods? How are you determining whether the subset is replaced with the whole set? Also, I recommend using [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to troubleshoot.

Comment: edited to satisfy your request. Still pseudo-code as the details of the implementation are not the problem if the implementation explained above is correct, which apparently it isn't...

Comment: I actually managed to solve my problem, due to insufficiently thorough debugging. I guess the temptation of going blazing guns on the Internet instead of doing one's work properly is sometimes hard to resist. Thanks for your time and have a nice day!